# Swift 3 How to show different Array to the same second View controller cell

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift3, ios10, didselectrowatindexpath

I am a fresh new `iOS` Programmer, try to do first app with `Swift3`. It is like the different Zones Area data shared func. There is a problem wish could be help, deeply really appreciate it !!

I got two `ViewController` and one cell in each View. 
A `ViewController`  with A cell
B `ViewController`  with B cell

in A view I have an `Array` for example :

```
var USA = [String]()

USA = ["NY", "NJ", "CF", "LA", "WD"]
```

And if

```
NY = ["zone one", "zone two", "zone three", "zone 4", "zone 5"]
NJ = ["eastZone", "southZone", "northZone", "westZone"]
CF = ["midtown", "downtown", "uptown", "county"]
LA = ["firstZone", "SndZone", "ThreeZone", "fourZone", "fiveZone"]
WD = ["eastPart", "westPart", "downPart", "upPart", "countyPart"]
```

so in the A view I can show the cell by :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return USA.count
}
```

total have 5 rows

then use this func to select the row you want

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

The Question is how can I show

```
["firstZone", "SndZone", "ThreeZone", "fourZone", "fiveZone"] in B View cell, if I selected A View's row "LA"
```

after i selected the LA, the B view can show 5 rows:

```
["firstZone", "SndZone", "ThreeZone", "fourZone", "fiveZone"]
```

If I selected NY it could show the NY's array data in B view that is what i need~

I want to show different cell data when I selected different row between Two `ViewController` is it possible by any smart way ?? or I need more `ViewController` or Class? please help me !!thank you so much~

Comment: you want to show in single screen or different ?

Comment: I want to show in single screen "B view controller's cell" with different data (zones) from "A view controller's citys"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your data as an array of objects where each object contains a sub-array.

e.g.:

```
class Location {
    var name: String
    var sections: [String]

    init(_ key: String, sections: [String]) {
        name = key
        self.sections = sections
    }
}

let USA = [Location("NY", sections: ["zone one", "zone two", "zone three", "zone 4", "zone 5"]),
       Location("NJ", sections: ["eastZone", "southZone", "northZone", "westZone"]),
       Location("CF", sections: ["midtown", "downtown", "uptown", "county"]),
       Location("LA", sections: ["firstZone", "SndZone", "ThreeZone", "fourZone", "fiveZone"]),
       Location("WD", sections: ["eastPart", "westPart", "downPart", "upPart", "countyPart"])]
```

For your A controller, the cell shows `Location.name` for the object at `IndexPath.row`.  For your B controller, pass the selected `Location` object and use the `Location.sections` count and items for your cells.